# jQuery .load() another page which contains prism.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prism.js

I'm creating a website that uses jQuery .load() to present content that is stored in divs on another .html page, as follows

index.html head:

```
<link href="css/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prism.js"></script>
```

index.html:

```
$('#content').load('project_info.html #example', function() { $(this).fadeIn(".25s"); });
```

project_info.html's corresponding div:

```
<div id="example">
<pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the prism.js code block to display correctly, and while

```
 <pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
```

works properly when I embed it in index.html, it won't seem to inherit the prism.js file, just the prism.css stylesheet. It seems the prism.js file won't manipulate the "content" div. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you load the remote content onto your page, you'll need to manually apply prism to it. After some brief search, looks like prism.js provides this method:

```
highlightElement: function(element, async, callback) { ... }
```

I'm assuming can use `Prism.highlightElement(document.getElementById('example'))` to highlight the code inside `#example`.

(Also see this example: https://github.com/PrismJS/prism/blob/b551696fbdf8905d52ca67e1a9ae50a3ccfeab92/examples.js)